# Rails/Devise sign in page no longer needed---how to remove?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I recently put the sign in form onto my homepage instead of having an dedicated sign in page.

Any ideas on how to make it such that a user can no longer access the old sign in page?

Not sure if I can just remove the routes, remove the page, or force a redirect to homepage whenever the user may try to access the old resource.

Using:

Devise 2.0.0
Rails 3.2.13

Old sign in routes shown below:

[image]

Comment: just don't direct the user to the old one and use a before_filter on it.